# Where is Firebase-Web refresh token stored?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

Firebase Authentication Session is long-lived and it does not expire until some special actions [[1]](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-sessions) .

I understand that it is brought by long-lived refresh token, but I want to know where the refresh token is stored, especially on our browser. Browser provides some places to persist strings: Cookie and Local Storage. There are some pros and cons for those storages, so I want to know to which does firebase auth persists its refresh token (and possibly how & why).

Comment: You could certainly examine the [source code](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk) to find out for yourself what web API it uses.  Probably [web storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API).  The actual location likely varies per browser.

Comment: Did you see https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/auth-state-persistence?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Dong Stevenson, I found the description on the source code:
https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/blob/0765b5e19c3e949bb33233ee52c8e33f01418e54/packages/auth/test/integration/webdriver/persistence.test.ts

It is saved on IndexDB or LocalStorage.