# How does Firebase auth store and refresh sessions/tokens?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am new to Firebase Auth and some questions came up to me:

1. When I sign in (and stay logged in), where is that stored on my android device?
2. I assume Firebase uses tokens? How long are they valid and are they only refreshed while my app is running or is there some kind of service involved that refreshes tokens no matter if my app is opened by the user or not?

Comment: I think this answer may also answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71822066/11726273

Comment: @IlanRosenbaum Thanks, but that's for the web version. I want to know about native Android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should review the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-sessions):

> Firebase Authentication sessions are long lived. Every time a user signs in, the user credentials are sent to the Firebase Authentication backend and exchanged for a Firebase ID token (a JWT) and refresh token. Firebase ID tokens are short lived and last for an hour; the refresh token can be used to retrieve new ID tokens. Refresh tokens expire only when one of the following occurs:
>
> - The user is deleted
> - The user is disabled
> - A major account change is detected for the user. This includes events like password or email address updates.

Also see:

- [Is the firebase access token refreshed automatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49656489/is-the-firebase-access-token-refreshed-automatically)

The SDK uses app local storage for the token.

Comment: thanks for the pointer! "The SDK uses app local storage for the token." - do you know more details on this? Is that a shared preference? How could I find the token on a rooted device? (just for learning purposes)

Comment: It shouldn't be too hard to dig around in the files to find it, especially if it's the only thing you've added to a basic app.